# Electrum - How to check that a payment is done

Tags: bitcoin

I'm using [Electrum](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/console.html)

I have a website where I accept Bitcoin.
I generate a new address, give it to the customer and then I wait for the customer to pay.

How can I see if the payment is done or not using the JsonRPC?

I will have thousands of payment per day. So I can't do balance diff.

I tried to use "notify" : `'notify', {'address': address, 'URL':'http://localhost:8000/payement/success/'}`
That work, i receive the request on my URL but i don't get any parameters to help me, like amount received or tx id of transaction.

Comment: Did you figure out any solution to this? Bitcoin Core wallet (non-HD) has a wallet-notify config variable that you can set (you can specify a callback url or any other local command line instruction there). Don't know how to use Electrum for this. Appreciate a reply.

Comment: Hi ! No i didn't, i forfeit on this lol :)